# sql where clause with case & like

Tags: sql, mysqli

Blockquote

```
DECLARE @Symbol nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @EnDate1 Datetime;
DECLARE @StDate1 Datetime;
SET @Symbol = 'RIM12f'
SET @EnDate1 = '05/08/2012 9:00'
SET @StDate1 = '05 / 07 / 2012 12 : 00'
SELECT  *
FROM   Siri
WHERE (DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, Date)) BETWEEN @StDate1 AND @EnDate1)
  AND  CASE Symbol = WHEN @Symbol = 'ALL'
                     THEN Symbol
                     ELSE Symbol LIKE LEFT(@Symbol, len(@Symbol) - 3) + '%'
       END
```

it does not works as same but
it works with else @Symbol
but i need all symbols like LEFT(@Symbol, len(@Symbol) - 3) + '%' if @Symbol other than all

Comment: Don't think it's sql server, looks like one of those unholy confabulations like FORBOL to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify you Case expression:

```
 Symbol LIKE CASE @Symbol WHEN 'ALL'
                     THEN Symbol
                     ELSE LEFT(@Symbol, len(@Symbol) - 3) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Symbol nvarchar(50); 
DECLARE @LikeSymbol nvarchar(50); 

DECLARE @EnDate1 Datetime; 
DECLARE @StDate1 Datetime; 
SET @Symbol = 'RIM12f' 
SET @EnDate1 = '05/08/2012 9:00' 
SET @StDate1 = '05 / 07 / 2012 12 : 00' 
SET @LikeSymbol = LEFT(@Symbol, length(@Symbol) - 3) + '%'
SELECT  * 
FROM   Siri 
WHERE (DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, Date)) BETWEEN @StDate1 AND @EnDate1) 
AND (
(@Symbol = 'All')
OR
(Symbol Like @LikeSymbol)
)
```

A guess seeing as the intent of your query is far from clear

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have in `CASE` both `=` and nested `LIKE`.. you can use LIKE or using `OR` and `AND` constructions.. (like suggested @Tony Hopkinson)

Here is modified case:

```
Symbol like CASE WHEN @Symbol = 'ALL'
                     THEN Symbol
                     ELSE LEFT(@Symbol, len(@Symbol) - 3) + '%'
END
```

Comment: Sorry, Error on copy paste, try again.. i just run it on SQL SERVER 2000 and it's working OK